# How to set a variable via asynched xmlhttprequest response

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to achieve can be done easily if I make synched requests, but since it is deprecated I am now updating my script to work correctly with asynch calls instead so that when the other method stops working the script continues working.

The current code that I am using is as follows:

```
function GET(a) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    data;
  request.open("GET", a, false);
  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(4 == request.readyState) data = request.responseText;
  };
  request.send();
  return data;
}

function getObject(a) {
  var constructor = {};
  constructor.property1 = 'something1';
  constructor.property2 = 'something2';
  constructor.property3 = 'something3';
  constructor.property4 = true;
  if(a && a.attribute === null) constructor.property5 = GET('/url-location');
  return constructor;
}

var object = getObject(a);
if(object.property5) doSomethingWith(object);
```

As you can see the request is conducted at run-time in order to set a value to the constructor object. It works because it is synchronus and the function waits for a response before moving on, allowing a value to be set before the object is returned.

However, the same does not happen when the request runs asynch because the function moves on without waiting for the response.

My problem is evident; Is it possible to replicate the same behaviour with asynch requests? If not then how could I achieve the same structure without modifying too much? And by this I mean that the creation of the constructor object requires to be created in the way I presented; to set multiple properties in sequence once getObject is called and return it when it is finished.

I cannot use libraries, so no jQuery, Node, etc. I am also avoiding timed/looped functions.

One more detail that I almost forgot: the GET function is used by another function with a different structure, but with a similar objective, so this isn't as simple as changing the GET function to work just with the example I provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a callback function into your `GET`, and call it:

```
function GET(a, callback) {                                     // <== Change here
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();                           // <== No need for `data`
  request.open("GET", a, true);
  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(4 == request.readyState) callback(request.responseText); // <== Change here
  };
  request.send();
}
```

Usage (also with callback, I didn't call out the changes, they're like the above):

```
function getObject(a, callback) { 
  var constructor = {};
  constructor.property1 = 'something1';
  constructor.property2 = 'something2';
  constructor.property3 = 'something3';
  constructor.property4 = true;
  if(a && a.attribute === null) GET('/url-location', function(data) {
    constructor.property5 = data;
    callback(constructor);
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
getObject(a, doSomethingWith);
```

Or if you really need that `object` variable:

```
var object;
getObject(a, function(data) {
    object = data;
    doSomethingWith(object);
});
```

...but note that `object` will be `undefined` until the callback happens (e.g., until the XHR call completes).

Another way is with [promises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises), but it still involves callbacks, just a different (and arguably more powerful/convenient) style of chaining them.

Comment: Problem is that with your example `var object` will not get anything in return because neither function is returning the constructor

Comment: @Shadow: Right: A function that does its work asynchronously **can't** return the results, that's what the callback's for. That's why there's no `var object` above: `getObject` calls `GET`, then `GET` calls the callback inside `getObject` (later, when the work is complete), and `getObject` calls its callback with the result -- and its callback is `doSomethingWith`, which receives the object.

Comment: But I need `var object` to exist for other functions as well, not just the one I included in the example. There are more conditions that depend on that object which will fail because your solution does not return an object and I can't see how your solution could be apllied to the case correctly, otherwise everytime a condition is met it will be forced to do another httprequest, every single time, instead of just once.

Comment: @Shadow: Fine, you just put the variable back and write to it in the callback; I've updated the end of the answer to show how. But again: A function cannot *return* the value if the value is retrieved asynchronously. Which is fine, you just have to get used to working with callbacks, which is much easier than it seems once you get used to it.

Comment: It was so simple... I was trying to return the constructor by a far more complicated way, but you ended providing the most simple solution. It seems to be working so far, so I will accept yours as the correct answer. It is true, I need to get used to callbacks since synch will be scrapped, time to learn some new things that I should have learned from the beginning. Thank you for taking the time with this, I really appreciated it. 
PS: You left the open request as "false" in your answer. It is ok for me because I removed it on my end, but for completeness it would be best if you could fix it.